# read image in 2d array C++ and save it

Tags: c++, image

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // for file I/O
#define WIDTH 128
#define HEIGHT 128
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char unchar;

class MImage
{

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////read

public:
    void readimage()
    {

        imageData = new unchar*[HEIGHT]; // create new array size: height of image.

        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            imageData[i] = new unchar[WIDTH]; //create matrix.          
        }

        //image I/O
        pInFile = new ifstream;
        pInFile->open("L.bmp", ios::in | ios::binary); // open fileName and read as binary.

        pInFile->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageHeaderData), 1078); //read bmp header data into array.

        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            pInFile->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageData[i]), WIDTH); //read row into each array entry.   
        }

        pInFile->close(); //close stream.
    }

public:
    void write()
    {

        //smoothFilter();
        pOutFile = new ofstream;
        pOutFile->open("output.bmp", ios::out | ios::binary);
        pOutFile->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageHeaderData), 1078); //write header data onto output

        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {

            pOutFile->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageData[i]), WIDTH); // write new image data.

        }

        pOutFile->close(); //close stream
    }

public:
    ifstream* pInFile;
    ofstream* pOutFile;
    unchar imageHeaderData[1078]; //.bmp header data with offset 1078.  unchar** imageData;

};
int main()
{

    MImage abc;
    abc.readimage();
    abc.write();

    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to read image in a 2d array so that i could do some processing on it. i have used the code above but saved file is giving error.
what i am doing is first reading a .bmp file 128x128 then saving it in an other .bmp file. but when i try to open output file it gives error "file is corrupted or large in size"

Comment: That code made my formatter hurl. I had to fix it by hand. Crom, dude, what did you write that with?

Comment: Don't use macros, why would you only want to ever support 128x128 images? Use vectors so you don't leak memory and you can copy your class without it breaking. Why are the filestreams class members? You only use them inside the function, and they shouldn't be dynamically allocated.

Comment: There is no check to ensure the file is 128x128. The header contents are totally ignored, so you have no clue how the image data is encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps ;)
I skipped error checking but you should add it to the final code. For writing a .bmp image, wirte BITMAPFILEHEADER first, then BITMAPINFOHEADER and at the end the actual raw data

```
FILE* filePtr;
int error;
unsigned int count;
BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;
int imageSize;
unsigned char* bitmapImage;

// Open the height map file in binary.
error = fopen_s(&filePtr, filename, "rb");

// Read in the file header.
count = fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, filePtr);

// Read in the bitmap info header.
count = fread(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, filePtr);

// Save the dimensions of the terrain.
Width= bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth;
Height= bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight;

// Calculate the size of the bitmap image data.
imageSize = Width* Height* 3;

// Allocate memory for the bitmap image data.
bitmapImage = new unsigned char[imageSize];

// Move to the beginning of the bitmap data.
fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);

// Read in the bitmap image data.
count = fread(bitmapImage, 1, imageSize, filePtr);

// Close the file.
error = fclose(filePtr);
```

Don't forget to delete `bitmapImage` or use `std::vector` instead